# Add button in Account common report using custom module - Odoo

Tags: odoo-9

I'm trying to add button "Print XLS" in Account's common reports using custom module, I can able to add button directly in ***account_report_common_view.xml*** as below,

```
  <record id="account_common_report_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Common Report</field>
        <field name="model">account.common.report</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Report Options">
            <field name="company_id" invisible="1"/>
            <group col="4">
                <field name="target_move" widget="radio"/>
                <field name="date_from"/>
                <field name="date_to"/>
            </group>
            <group col="3">
                <field name="journal_ids" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="check_report" string="Print" type="object" default_focus="1" class="oe_highlight"/>
                or
                <button name="check_report_xlsx" string="Print XLS" type="object" default_focus="1" class="oe_highlight"/> -- ADDED HERE
                or 
                <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel" />
            </footer>
        </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Now i want to do this in custom module. how can i add this button in new custom module ?

Answer (score 0):

To create a module you can follow this guide:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html

To modify a view you can inherit it, and add, for istance, a botton.
This inside a new record, model="ir.ui.view":

```
<record id="your_name" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name"> A name</field> 
<field name="model">account.common.report</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.account_common_report_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <!-- new tab added      -->
                <xpath expr="//notebook/page" position="after">
```

Be sure that you have add your view inside the directory of your module (typical view/account_report_common_view_button.xml ) 
and add it to the manifest 
data : ["view/account_report_common_view_button.xml",
]

Andrea